# Split csv file without getting incomplete lines

Tags: java

I have successfully split a csv but it sometimes has some file chunks with incomplete last lines. The file is wrapped using a RandomAccessFile object. Here is my code:

```
long sourceSize = raf.length();
long bytesPerSplit = sourceSize / splits;
long remainingBytes = sourceSize % splits;

int maxReadBufferSize = 8 * 1024; // 8 KB
for (int destIx = 1; destIx <= splits; destIx++) {
    // TODO: change so that first name is the year involved
    try(BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(destination + "\\chunk" + destIx + ".csv"))) {
      if (bytesPerSplit > maxReadBufferSize) {
        long numReads = bytesPerSplit / maxReadBufferSize;
        long numRemainingRead = bytesPerSplit % maxReadBufferSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < numReads; i++) {
          readWrite(raf, bw, maxReadBufferSize);
        }
        if (numRemainingRead > 0) readWrite(raf, bw, numRemainingRead);
      } else readWrite(raf, bw, bytesPerSplit);
    }
```

I thought of checking if the last byte array read would have a newline at the end beforehand and if not increasing the buffer size to be read but I don't know if it's possible to do that with a RandomAccessFile object

Comment: Are you `.flush()`ing and `.close()`ing the output stream?

Comment: It's in a try-with-resources block